# Использование log4j в lotus domino

Tags: java

Всем добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить log4j для lotus domino. Необходимо, чтобы кроме StartTime выводилось ещё и FinishTime (если это вообще возможно).

Comment: Ренат, не понятна идея. Что значит FinishTime и куда его надо выводить?

Answer (score 0):

Я кажется понял о чём речь. Надо смотреть в коде аппендера, возможно придётся в него внести правки. В классе `LogDocument` есть соответствующий метод `setFinishTime`, но надо его как-то вызвать в момент последнего сохранения документа. Скорее всего это в `AbstractAppender` в `close()`, `writeDocument()` или `releaseAppend()`

Для тех, кто не в курсе речь идёт об [Log4j Domino Appenders](http://domino-log4j.sourceforge.net)